# Within a dict create a list of random numbers of a given length that reprocesses each time its referenced

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hi am trying to create a list of random numbers of length n within a dict that reprocesses each time it is called. To do this and generate a single random variable the following code works for me:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform as sp_randuniform

some_dict = {"some_var": sp_randuniform(0, 1)}
```

Each time this dictionary is referenced it generates a new random variable. What I am trying to do is essentially do this but to have multiple random variables returned in a list of length n. Something akin to:

```
some_dict = {"some_var": [sp_randuniform(0, 1) for x in range(n)]}
#desired output when referenced
some_dict = {"some_var": [new_rnd1,new_rnd2,...n]}
```

However, obviously this does not work as it returns frozen variables ('rv_frozen'). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using some_dict.update() ?

Comment: It does not work in this application and returns an error:    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'.  The dictionary is being called as part of RandomizedSearchCV() from sklearn and seems to have a problem using update.

Comment: you get NoneType returned, whichmeans your dict gets lost somewhere along the way. I'd try to create a function that would be used to return reference then update the dict

Comment: I cannot understand why it would get lost for the later method, but not the first which works when all that is being changed is .update() is being added to some_dict within the RandomizedSearchCV() function. Is there no way to just agument the top code to include n random vars instead of just the one?

Answer (score 0):

The `sp_randuniform` method seems to have a problem. Also, using the `.__dict__` did not seem to give any solutions or an explanation. But, you can use the following code as an alternative for what you are trying to create

```
import random
size = 5
some_dict={"some_var" : [random.uniform(0,1) for x in range(size)]}
```

All the best!!